# zend modules default controller

Tags: zend-framework

Hy guys,

how can i set the default modules controller ??

i need that if there isn't controller in module folder, i come at default module controller and view!

for example i type into the browser: 
http://192.168.1.100/Testmoduli/public/givep/

where givep is my module without IndexController.php, now i need to come at my default module (artapp) into IndexController.php

```
resources.frontController.defaultController = "index" 
resources.frontController.defaultAction = "index" 
resources.frontController.defaultModule = "artapp" 
resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules"
```

thanks!

EDIT:

so..

If I try to launch an action that does not exist, it is automatically launched in the same action in the form of default?

to launch this action can i only catch the action into controller error??

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in your ErrorController :

```
// in errorAction()
if($this->_error->type == 'EXCEPTION_NO_CONTROLLER'){
     // redirect or forward where you want
}
```

Comment: but i don't know wich is the controller! depends of user type! for example for example, if http://192.168.1.100/Testmoduli/public/givep/ i need to come into IndexController.php but http://192.168.1.100/Testmoduli/public/givep/main i need to go into MainController.php of default module!!

Comment: if i remember well you can extract the controller name from $this->_error->request->getParam('controller').

Comment: ok!! only this way?? is there other methods to set default folder to search controller??

Comment: setting a default controller would just replace the fact that module/ does not point to module/index but to module/thenewdefaultcontroller, and this would apply to *all* your modules. And in ZF, a request to a non-existent controller generates a 404 error, if you want to change it you have to catch the error and do your own thing instead. Don't forget to "accept" the answer if it works

Comment: ok thanks! so if a controller module does not exist, there is another way to take the default controller? only with forward from errorcontroller ?